# How set nav-header to right side - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How set header item to right side in wordpress ?
I tried with align = "right" but didnt work.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="container">
<!--site-header-->
<header class="site-header">
<div class="hd_search">
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
<span>
<h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name');?></h1></a> </span>
<h5> <?php bloginfo('description'); ?> <?php if(is_page('portfolio')){?>
- Thank you for viewing my work
<?php } ?> </h5>
<div class="header" >
<nav class="site-nav" align="left">
<?php
    $args= array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
    );
?>
<?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
</nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

[Set header to red arctangle. Click to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcYHl.png)

Comment: Where do you have your header actually?

Comment: Did you see picture ?

Comment: Yes, should have deleted the comment

Comment: Did the answer work?

Comment: No. Its doesnt work.

Comment: Have you tried inside the CSS add float:right ?

Comment: Yes but heades is still up. I know does not make sense but my prof ask me this on exam...

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168900/10701729

Comment: I know where is problem. I must change code in home page file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actuallu this is because of `<header>` does not support `align` atrribute, just replace it with `div` instead. Note that html5 does no longer support `align` attribute, so I suggest you to use CSS instead.
For example replace this `<div align="center">` with `<div style="text-align:center;border:1px solid red">`, for the result you need check CSS [reference manual](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_references.asp) and HTML [reference from w3school.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)
However, the property you need is the CSS attribute `float`, you can simply add to your `<header class="site-header">` with `<header class="site-header" style="float: right">`